# boundingRectWithSize: doesn't respect lineBreakMode settings

Tags: ios, nsstring, uikit, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to calculate font size to fit text into 2 lines (with variable font size).

In storyboard label has fixed font size, word wrapping setting is `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`.

In cases, when first word is longer than line width my code doesn't work (for iOS 8).

E.g. for "Verylongline 45" in iOS 7.1 `boundingRectWithSize:` will calculate `rect` for line (w:50, h:60):

```
Verylongl
ine
45
```

It keeps width bounds but makes word wrap after first word anyway. In iOS 8 it returns rect for text (w:50, h:40):

```
Verylongl
ine 45
```

Because or that difference code to calculate acceptable font size doesn't work. iOS 8 can fit much bigger font in 2 lines, ignoring wrap setting.

This code is a category method to adjust font size for label to fit it in 2 lines. Works for iOS 7.1, doesn't in iOS 8.0

```
for (int i = maxSize; i>minSize; i--) {

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.font.fontName size:(CGFloat)i];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    [style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CGRect rect = [self.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style} context:nil];

    if (rect.size.height <= self.frame.size.height) {
        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.font.fontName size:(CGFloat)i];
        break;
    }
}
```

do you have any idea how to make it work in iOS 8?

Comment: any solution for this ?